# What is "multiple variable assignment" really called?

Tags: javascript, naming-conventions

I do this from time to time, especially in Javascript to store references to deeply nested properties in objects, but I am not sure on what this would be called. Multiple variable assigning? Variable reference assignment?

```
myVar = myObject.myProperty = value
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally known as "chained assignment".

It is also important to differentiate the fact that you're not just assigning multiple variables, but you are assigning the return value of the deeper assignment operation.  That is why it is a "chain" rather than some form of combined operation.